# Evidences of Manzoni's influence on Dun Karm poems

Tags: italian-language, maltese-language, alessandro-manzoni, dun-karm

According to [Britannica Online Encyclopedia](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Dun-Karm), Dun Karm is considered the national poet of Malta:

> **Dun Karm**, pseudonym of **Carmelo Psaila**, (born Oct. 18, 1871, Zebbug, Gozo, Malta—died Oct. 13, 1961, Valletta), Malta’s national poet, sometimes called “the bard of Malta,” or “the Chaucer of Malta.”

The [allpoetry website](https://allpoetry.com/Dun-Karm) claims that there was an influence of Italian writer Alessandro Manzoni on Dun Karm works:

> The influence of the Italian poet and novelist Alessandro Manzoni can be seen in his pacifism and Karm also found expression in spiritual solitude which reflects in his scenes of country life.

Can anyone provide evidences of such affirmation?